# How adjust data interchange between two windows without deviating from mvvm?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Let us have two viewmodels for the main and dialog window. Provided that element for show target list located in main window, how to transfer data from dialog window to the target listElement?

Comment: It is common for dialogs to have a result that they pass back to whatever called or instantiated them - that result can then be used however you need.

Comment: Your dialog should have a mvvm class just like any other, on the closing event you can read any properties that you need: a boolean expresing yes or no, an id from a list, a input string, a filename. It offers endless possibilities